# Use of config.xml in ionic project with capacitor

Tags: ionic3, capacitor

As you can see in the screenshot below, the content of the file config.xml mentions Cordova but my Ionic project is configured using capacitor.

What is the use of config.xml?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor includes some files, like the `config.xml` for the Cordova plugin compatibility. Notice that you also have a `capacitor.config.json` file, that’s the Capacitor config file.